# count repeated values in column for unique fileds

Tags: vba, excel, count

I have 2 qns that should be performed in VBA Code.
1. I want to count the total number of times a particular string has repeated for more than 40 unique values in a column.how this can be achieved.

for eg- unique values like Apple, banana, grapes (40 more unique values) are repeated in a column and I want the count of individual string like this.

```
Apple- 30 times repeated
banana- 4 times repeated.
```

2. after taking the total number of each strings,I want to count them with a specific criteria.

Eg- count apple, only if the cost if above 40
    count grapes, only if the cost if above 40

can any1 pls help on this, how to implement this in VBA Code.

Comment: Is this homework by any chance? Have you attempted any code yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The following code adds all strings from Column A into a collection structure, sorts it while counting each unique value and stores each unique value and the corresponding sum in a dictionary structure. The results are then printed to the Immediate window. Hope this helps.

```
Sub main()


'variables
Dim colCollection As New Collection
Dim x, q As Variant
Dim cellValue As String
Dim j, i, count As Integer
Dim numbers As New Scripting.Dictionary 'NOTE: add microsoft scripting Runtime Ref


x = 1 'collections start at 1

    While Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "A").Value <> "" 'while cell is not empty
        cellValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "A").Value 'store string value from cell
        colCollection.Add (cellValue) ' add entry from cell to collection
        x = x + 1 'increment
    Wend

    'Sort collection (bubbble sort) and record number of each unique item
    For i = colCollection.count To 2 Step -1 'count down from collection
        For j = 1 To i - 1
            'bubble up item
            If colCollection(j) > colCollection(j + 1) Then
                colCollection.Add colCollection(j), After:=j + 1
                colCollection.Remove j
            End If
        Next j
        'finding count of unique item
        If i <> colCollection.count Then 'if not at last item (can't compare 2 items when only given 1)
           If i = 2 Then 'if at end
                numbers.Add colCollection(i), count + 3 'add sum to dictionary with corresponding key value
            Else
                If StrComp(colCollection(i + 1), colCollection(i), 1) = 0 Then 'if same string
                    count = count + 1 'increment count
                Else
                    numbers.Add colCollection(i + 1), count + 1 'add sum to dictionary with corresponding key value
                    count = 0 'reset count
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i


'loop through dictionary
For Each q In numbers.Keys
    Debug.Print q & "- " & numbers.Item(q); " times repeated."
Next


End Sub
```